# Presentation.Core reference not found

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to open and build [a project](https://github.com/mbrenn/direct2donwpf/) in Visual Studio 2012 on Win 7. The project requires some `SharpDX` references which I don't have. But that is not my problem! I'm getting an error that I'm also missing the `Presentation.Core` and the rest of the default references required for a WPF project. What can be the problem?

[image]

The target framework is set to .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: Clean the solution, close Visual Studio, open the solution and try to rebuild. Post the result.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath When I rebuild the project, the NuGet Package Manager tries to download the missing SharpDX references but doesn't complete the download and it stays that way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need libraries. Delete all references, where contains marker 'warning' and add they to project. If you don't have libraries - it is bad. Download them.

Comment: Thanks Denis, I'm trying to download them via NuGet. It doesn't download them though.

Comment: @Vahid what you can't download?

Comment: It says that Nuget Unable to connect to remote server

Comment: @Vahid, I just went to the NuGet and found SharpDX for example. Possible problem NuGet. Restart your IDE or wait until start working.

Comment: I try downloading them using `Install-Package SharpDX -Version 2.6.3`

Comment: @Vahid Try open NuGet Package Manager and find SharpDX

Comment: Thanks Denis, I will try that too.